# Default file open options issue

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, file-association

I want to double click PDF's gives me Google Chrome Browser 64.0.3282 for Views (quick just to read)
BUT...
I when I right click to 'edit' I want Word 2013 to open the PDF.

I'm guessing a Reg hack, as the normal default associate isn't sufficient?
But if there is a menu option, if anyone can enlighten me?

Comment: Please also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).